# Wordpress - Can't paginate gallery results

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a custom filter to add pagination to a gallery.

This is the code:

```
function mysite_custom_gallery($output, $attr)
{
    global $post;

    //GALLERY SETUP STARTS HERE----------------------------------------//
    if (isset($attr['orderby'])) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby($attr['orderby']);
        if (! $attr['orderby']) {
            unset($attr['orderby']);
        }
    }

    $order = 'ASC';
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => $order,
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'dl',
        'icontag'    => 'dt',
        'captiontag' => 'dd',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'thumbnail',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $orderby = 'menu_order ID';

    if (! empty($include)) {
        $include      = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include);
        $_attachments = get_posts(array('include'        => $include,
                                        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                                        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                                        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                        'order'          => $order,
                                        'orderby'        => $orderby
        ));

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ($_attachments as $key => $val) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    }
    if (empty($attachments)) {
        return '';
    }
    //GALLERY SETUP END HERE------------------------------------------//

    //PAGINATION SETUP START HERE-------------------------------------//
    $current  = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $per_page = 24;
    //$offset = ($page-1) * $per_page;
    $offset = ($current - 1) * $per_page;
    $big    = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    $total       = sizeof($attachments);
    $total_pages = round($total / $per_page);
    if ($total_pages < ($total / $per_page)) {
        $total_pages = $total_pages + 1;
    }
    //PAGINATION SETUP END HERE-------------------------------------//

    //GALLERY OUTPUT START HERE---------------------------------------//
    $output = "<div class=\"gallery-images\">\n";
    $output .= '<div class="row">';
    $counter = 0;
    $pos     = 0;
    foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) {
        $pos++;

        if (($counter < $per_page) && ($pos > $offset)) {
            $counter++;
            $output .= '<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 box-gallery">';
            $largetitle = get_the_title($attachment->ID);
            /*$largeimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'full');*/
            $linkimg = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);
            $img     = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, 'mlt-medium');
            $output .= " <a href=\"$linkimg\" title=\"$largetitle\"><img src=\"$img[0]\" width=\"$img[1]\" height=\"$img[2]\" alt=\"\" /></a>\n";
            $output .= '</div>';
        }

    }
    $output .= "<div class=\"clear\"></div>\n";
    $output .= "</div>\n";
    $output .= "</div>\n";
    //GALLERY OUTPUT ENDS HERE---------------------------------------//

    //PAGINATION OUTPUT START HERE-------------------------------------//
    $output .= '<div class="pagination">';
    $output .= $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big) ),
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $total_pages,
        'mid_size' => 5
    ) );
    $output .= "</div>\n";

    //PAGINATION OUTPUT ENDS HERE-------------------------------------//

    return $output;
}
```

And this is the filter:

```
add_filter('post_gallery', 'mysite_custom_gallery', 10, 2);
```

The gallery is correctly paginated every 24 images and event the pagination is correct, it shows the correct number of pages.

The problem is that if I click on a link nothing happen, and I can't understand why is not working.

The generated url for the second page seems correct:

```
http://mysite.app/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/page/2/
```

but if I try to click or visit the link I'm redirected to:

```
http://mysite.app/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/
```

so it remove the `page/2` segments.
Can please someone help me to find the issue?

**Edit**
here the pagination source:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/page/2/">2</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/page/3/">3</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/page/4/">4</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/page/5/">5</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/page/6/">6</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="/photogallery/argentina/buenos-aires/buenos-aires/page/2/">Next »</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Website doens't load popperly. Please include the source output of the pagination within your question

Comment: Looks like it is getting the get variable paged yet I guess your URL contains the name page. Could you try changing `$current  = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` with `$current  = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;` EDIT: same also applies to the paging OUTPUT

Comment: tried but didn't work

Comment: The link you provided is that a example or the real link? Do you mind me taking a look at the live example of possible?

Comment: can we discuss in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121349/discussion-between-christian-giupponi-and-s-lenders).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable redirect for your post type, for example:

```
function redirect_canonical_off($redirect_url)
{
    if (is_singular('your_custom_post_type_slug')) {
        $redirect_url = false;
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter("redirect_canonical", "redirect_canonical_off");
```

Make sure to replace `your_custom_post_type_slug`